# Looks like @ionic/app-scripts isn't installed in this project

Tags: ionic3, angular5

I just started learning IONIC. i installed the latest version of node from nodejs website and installed the latest version of IONIC by executing the command below

`$ npm install -g ionic cordova`

then, i created a project by executing the command below

`$ ionic start motorspecs blank`

when i tried to run the app by executing the command  `$ ionic serve`, i get some error. i am getting error like below

[click here to see error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9TKPU.png)

Please help to resolve the issue.  thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try running npm install in the project's Folder?

Comment: Yes.  i did that.

Answer (score 0):

Run `npm install` in the projects folder

Comment: Yes.  i did npm install  in the project folder only.   sometimes i am getting this issue. then automatically it resolves.  Still I don't know why it happens

Comment: It happens because what it said in your picture in the [INFO] @ionic/app-scripts is not installed and you do it with npm install